# How should I indicate that this css3 animation will not work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I have library with animation of blining cursor, and it change 2 properties, I found that it will not work on Android, so I put in JavaScript this code:

```
function isAndroid() {
    return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1;
}

if (false && (supportAnimations() && !isAndroid())) {
    animation = function(toggle) {
        if (toggle) {
            cursor.addClass('blink');
        } else {
            cursor.removeClass('blink');
        }
    };
} else {
    var animating = false;
    animation = function(toggle) {
        if (toggle && !animating) {
            animating = true;
            cursor.addClass('inverted');
            self.everyTime(500, 'blink', blink);
        } else if (animating && !toggle) {
            animating = false;
            self.stopTime('blink', blink);
            cursor.removeClass('inverted');
        }
    };
}
```

But then I wrote [animation that only use opacity](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#css-cursor) and it will work on Android. I don't want to include that animation with library, but I want to allow to use it.

How should I indicate that this animation can be run on Andorid too? Is it possible to write css rule that can be check in JavaScript? The only thing I see is `content` property and `:before` or `:after` but you can't get it's value from javascript.

Comment: theoretically the easiest way to do it is to assign the animations that you don't want to be excluded to a class and let it run always and assign the other animations to another class and remove that class whenever you want to ban it!

Comment: @AminJafari the problem is that, I don't know when not to run JS animation. If I do class based animation I will need to disable animation on Android even that it will work. (maybe I need to indicate this in client JS code).